# Is there a way to reduce scipy/numpy precision to reduce memory consumption?

Tags: numpy, scipy, numerical, matplotlib, fft

On my 64-bit Debian/Lenny system (4GByte RAM + 4GByte swap partition) I can successfully do:

```
v=array(10000*random([512,512,512]),dtype=np.int16)
f=fftn(v)
```

but with f being a `np.complex128` the memory consumption is shocking, and I can't do much more with the result (e.g modulate the coefficients and then `f=ifftn(f)` ) without a `MemoryError` traceback.

Rather than installing some more RAM and/or expanding my swap partitions, is there some way of controlling the scipy/numpy "default precision" and have it compute a complex64 array instead ?

I know I can just reduce it afterwards with `f=array(f,dtype=np.complex64)`; I'm looking to have it actually do the FFT work in 32-bit precision and half the memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't look like there's any function to do this in scipy's fft functions ( see http://www.astro.rug.nl/efidad/scipy.fftpack.basic.html ).

Unless you're able to find a fixed point FFT library for python, it's unlikely that the function you want exists, since your native hardware floating point format is 128 bits.  It does look like you could use the rfft method to get just the real-valued components (no phase) of the FFT, and that would save half your RAM.

I ran the following in interactive python:

```
>>> from numpy import *
>>>  v = array(10000*random.random([512,512,512]),dtype=int16)
>>> shape(v)
(512, 512, 512)
>>> type(v[0,0,0])
<type 'numpy.int16'>
```

At this point the RSS (Resident Set Size) of python was 265MB.

```
f = fft.fft(v)
```

And at this point the RSS of python 2.3GB.

```
>>> type(f)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> type(f[0,0,0]) 
<type 'numpy.complex128'>
>>> v = []
```

And at this point the RSS goes down to 2.0GB, since I've free'd up v.

Using "fft.rfft(v)" to compute real-values only results in a 1.3GB RSS.  (almost half, as expected)

Doing:

```
>>> f = complex64(fft.fft(v))
```

Is the worst of both worlds, since it first computes the complex128 version (2.3GB) and then copies that into the complex64 version (1.3GB) which means the peak RSS on my machine was 3.6GB, and then it settled down to 1.3GB again.

I think that if you've got 4GB RAM, this should all work just fine (as it does for me).  What's the issue?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the rfftn functions; yes those do the job nicely.  Peak usage for f=rfftn(v), f=array(f,dtype=np.complex64), f=irfftn(f) is 6224MByte in the inverse.  (Without the intermediate cast to complex64 it uses 7754MByte... a bit tight).

Comment: Is your production array size actually greater than 512^3?  I'm not sure why you're seeing something like 4x the RAM usage that I see in my example code above...

Comment: Please revise the bit where you say 'single-precision doesn't exist since your native hardware is 128-bit'—native hardware is no more 128 bits than 64 bits, and FFTW is very flexible in supporting both. As David's answer indicates, `scipy.fftpack.rfft` supports this: `scipy.fftpack.rfft(v.astype(np.float32)).dtype` returns `float32`. Unfortunately, Numpy support is lagging behind Scipy's, even in 2015: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6012

Answer (score 5):

Scipy 0.8 will have single precision support for almost all the fft code (The code is already in the trunk, so you can install scipy from svn if you need the feature now).